# Issue with deleting items from array in for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

So I am having a problem with deleting items from an array while in a for loop

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var array = [
"iPad",
"iPod",
"iPhone"
];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  let p = document.createElement('p');
  p.textContent = array[i];
  div.appendChild(p);

  p.onclick = function() {
    array.splice(array.indexOf(this, 1)); 
    this.remove(); 
    console.log(array);
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div>
      
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

So the problem is that when I click on an item to delete it, it doesn't delete that specific one. No matter which one I click on, it deletes starting from the bottom ("iPhone" to "iPod" to "iPad").

Visually, it deletes the right one but when I go to the console I can see that it deletes from the bottom up. Any help would be so very much appreciated.

Comment: provided link is not working

Comment: @SyedDaniyalAsif The cake is a lie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  let p = document.createElement('p'),
      a = array[i];
  p.textContent = a;
  div.appendChild(p);

  p.onclick = function() {
    array.splice(array.indexOf(a),1); 
    this.remove(); 
    console.log(array);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using `array.splice(array.indexOf(this, 1))` wrong, `this` gives you the clicked element where as array contains text inside that element, you need to do something like this:

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var array = [
"iPad",
"iPod",
"iPhone"
];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  let p = document.createElement('p');
  p.textContent = array[i];
  div.appendChild(p);

  p.onclick = function() {
    array.splice(array.indexOf(this.innerHTML),1); 
    this.remove(); 
    console.log(array);
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div>
      
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `onclick` function make the following changes.

```
p.onclick = function() {
    array.splice(array.indexOf(this.textContent),1); 
    this.remove(); 
    console.log(array);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

please have a look of `this` to `this.innerHTML`

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var array = [
"iPad",
"iPod",
"iPhone"
];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  let p = document.createElement('p');
  p.textContent = array[i];
  div.appendChild(p);

  p.onclick = function() {
array.splice(array.indexOf(this.innerHTML), 1); 
this.remove(); 
console.log(array);
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div>
      
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```